# Displaying Login Page Windows Authentication ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, adfs

I have a requirement to build a Website + Mobile App in Intranet using Windows Authentication Or more precisely ADFS.

I want to display Custom login Page to Users instead of Windows Security prompt and also authenticate the Mobile users.

I have gone through some articles which shows using mixed mode i.e, authenticate user using Windows and then use form authentication.

Is it recommended / Only workaround or any other better solutions preferable.

Thanks and Regards.

Update: I don't want this

[image: I don't want this!]

I want this instead:

[image: I want this!]

Comment: It depends on your requirenments. Right now your question is too broad

Comment: Currently I want to implement Login Functionality! Thats it. But using ADFS and OWIN also displaying Custom Login Page instead of Windows Prompt.